# Generic Interface take as argument propertyInfo.PropertyType

Tags: asp.net

I got some problem becouse i wanna give to generic interface a propertyInfo.Propertytype
and he shows error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'propertyInfo'
```

the interface call

```
 IListCombobox<propertyInfo.PropertyType>
```

the interface definition

```
   public interface IListCombobox<T>
{
    List<T> GetList();
}
```

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropertyType returns a Type object, so probably you need

```
IListCombobox<Type>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics are all about compile time safety. You cannot use it with Reflection and Propertynfo's and dynamic types that are known only at runtime. If you don't know the type at compile time forget about generics. Once you take the Reflection route you will have to walk on it till the end.

Comment: So maybe u know how to define in interface that it should has method that has GetList inside?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How are you calling this interface? Why are you using reflection in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Im trying to check if type of object is an interface.